# How to use Intersection between two list for multiple values in linq for unique records

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Hello to all Professionals,

Currently I am stucked at one query and not getting a proper solution to my problem. Here is the issue.

```
     Table 1                                  Table 2
   Form_id   Form No                       Form No Form Type
    1     10                                 10     101
    1     10                                 20     201   
    1     10                                 10     301   
    2     20                                 10     401
    3     30                                 30     501
```

I need to find out the unique Form_Id by joining these two tables. There is no parent child relationship between the two tables. I was trying with LINQ query using interesect function but could not get the desired output.

Desired Output :

```
Form_Id Form No Form Type
1         10      101       
2         20      201
3         30      501
```

Code I've tried:

```
var result=(from t1 in DBContext.table 1 
            join t2 in DBContext.table 2 on t1.FormNo equals t2.FormNo 
            Where FormTypeList.Contains(t2.FormType) 
            Select new { Form_Id=t1.Form_Id, 
                         FormNo=t2.FormNo, 
                         FormType=t2.FormType 
            }).ToList();
```

Thanking you.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried please.

Comment: How do you know that Form_ID 1 has Form Type 101 and not 301 or 401 ?

Comment: var result=(from t1 in DBContext.table 1
             join t2 in DBContext.table 2 on t1.FormNo equals t2.FormNo
              Where FormTypeList.Contains(t2.FormType) Select new {
   Form_Id=t1.Form_Id,
   FormNo=t2.FormNo,
   FormType=t2.FormType

}).ToList();

Comment: @Magnus Its predefined in the table

Answer (score 0):

Just slap on a `Distinct` after the query and you should be fine.

```
var result= (from t1 in DBContext.table1 
             join t2 in DBContext.table2 on t1.FormNo equals t2.FormNo 
             Where FormTypeList.Contains(t2.FormType) 
             Select new 
             { 
                Form_Id  = t1.Form_Id, 
                FormNo   = t2.FormNo, 
                FormType = t2.FormType 
             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried the above solution. But it gives me the repeated result and I want Form_Id unique in the result.

Comment: @NightKnight what gets repeated?